# Sidebar overlaps the main entry field of the “ask question” page

Tags: bug, design, opera, webkit

The sidebar with the similar questions or format hints overlap the entry field for the question asked.

On Stack Overflow:

> [image: on StackOverflow]

Here:

> [image: on StackEchange]

Comment: Any chance you've played with the browser zoom? What version of Opera on what OS?

Comment: I do used the zoom — but it did not make it better. Everything became smaller but the percentage of overlap stayed the same. — But I do have a minimum font size set. That's why «accessibility» was in the tag list.

Comment: Then edit the tag back in and put that information _in your question_: just tagging "accessibility" but not say what accessibility features you're using (or requesting) ins't helpful. And also please add your browser version and your OS while you're at it.